# Trying to get a row count in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is departments and the other is employees. The department id is a foreign key in the employees table. The employee table has a name and a flag saying if the person is part-time. I can have zero or more employees in a department. I'm trying to figure out out to get a list of all departments where a department has at least one employee and if it does have at least one employee, that all the employees are part time. I think this has to be some kind of subquery to get this. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT dept.name
    ,dept.id
    ,employee.deptid
    ,count(employee.is_parttime)
FROM employee
    ,dept
WHERE dept.id = employee.deptid
    AND employee.is_parttime = 1
GROUP BY employee.is_parttime
```

I would really appreciate any help at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join (properly) the tables and `group by department` with a condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select d.name, d.id, count(e.id) total 
from dept d inner join employee e
on d.id = e.deptid 
group by d.name, d.id
having total = sum(e.is_parttime)
```

The `inner join` returns only departments with at least 1 employee.
The column `is_parttime` (I guess) is a flag with values `0` or `1` so by summing it the result is the number of employees that are *part time* in the department and this number is compared to the total number of employees of the department.

Answer (score 1):

**As a preliminary aside**, I recommend expressing joins with the `JOIN` keyword, and segregating join conditions from filter conditions.  Doing so would make the original query look like so:

```
select dept.name, dept.id, employee.deptid, count(employee.is_parttime)
from employee
  join dept on dept.id = employee.deptid
where employee.is_parttime = 1
group by employee.is_parttime
```

It doesn't make much practical difference for inner joins, but it does make the structure of the data and the logic of the query a bit clearer.  On the other hand, it *does* make a difference for outer joins, and there is value in consistency.

---

As for the actual question, yes, one can rewrite the original query using a subquery or an inline view to produce the requested result.  (An "inline view" is technically what one should call an embedded query used as a table in the `FROM` clause, but some people lump these in with subqueries.)

**Example using a subquery**

```
select dept.name, dept.id
from dept
where dept.id in (
    select deptid
    from employee
    group by deptid
    having count(*) == sum(is_parttime)
  )
```

**Example using an inline view**

```
select dept.name, dept.id
from dept
  join (
    select deptid
    from employee
    group by deptid
    having count(*) == sum(is_parttime)
  )  pt_dept
  on dept.id = pt_dept.deptid
```

In each case, the subquery / inline view does most of the work.  It aggregates employees by department, then filters the groups (`HAVING` clause) to select only those in which the part-time employee count is the same as the total count.  Naturally, departments without any employees will not be represented.  If a list of department IDs would suffice for a list of departments, then that's actually all you need. To get the department names too, however, you need to combine that with data from the `dept` table, as demonstrated in the two example queries.

Comment: I'm confused by this statement: "To get the department names, however, you need to combine that with data from the dept table. You can do that either by using the employee query as a filter or by joining to it." Isn't the query already giving us the department names?

Comment: Yes, @KathyLori, The example queries presented do give the department names.  The referent of "that" in my statement was intended to be the subquery / inline view alone, as a continuation from the preceding paragraph.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It seems so simple once it's explained.